# initial zoom depending on device resolution

Tags: css

I would like to adjust initial zoom level for mobile devices(or certain resolutions) so that the content doesn't expand beyond the view space.
Is there an easier way than using media queries?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will adjust your website to device width and remove user zoom:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
```

Note: don't use `maximum-scale` if you still want your users to be able to zoom.

Comment: `initial-scale` would be adequate. To my mind the maximum scale is not something that should be denied the user. Some of us wear glasses you know. :)

Comment: I agree with @Paulie_D, please don't prevent zooming in. See why here: [The right to zoom](http://www.mobify.com/blog/the-right-to-zoom/).

Comment: @Paulie_D I know but it is needed if he wants to fix the zoom to a static value and have no scroll in all situations. And if you wear glasses, but still can't read on screen maybe you need new glasses :)) </joke>

Comment: Reading glasses don't necessarily cut it on a small screen. No joke :) +1 though.

Comment: @Paulie_D Don't know - I'm stuck with full time glasses :(